# Incorrect warning in Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode

The following code has a warning on the indicated line in Xcode.
Is this warning actually valid though?
If this is a valid warning how is that so?
If this warning is incorrect, what caused Xcode to create a warning on this line?

EDIT: Also, why is there no warning when `prevPtr` is referenced inside the while loop above the line where the warning occurs?

The warning reads `variable 'prevPtr' may be uninitialized when used here`
It is on the line `prevPtr->next = delPtr->next`

I believe that it is impossible to reach this line without the variable being initialized. Which would make this warning pointless.

```
void myEditor::deleteLine(int num)
{
    Line *delPtr = head;

    if (delPtr == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    if (head->linenum == num) {
        head = head->next;
    }
    else {
        Line *prevPtr;

        while (delPtr != NULL && delPtr->linenum != num) {
            prevPtr = delPtr;
            delPtr = delPtr->next;
        }

        if (delPtr == NULL) {
            cout << "Line " << num << " does not exist." << endl;
        }
        else {
            prevPtr->next = delPtr->next; // warning appears here
        }
    }

    delete delPtr;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the "Product > Analyze" menu item in Xcode, it'll show you *much* more details on this type of warning. Here's the results I got when I tried (after making some assumptions about the definition of `Line`):

[image: 1. 'prevPtr' initialize to a null pointer value; 2. Loop body executed 0 times; 3. Access to field 'next' results in a dereference of a null pointer (loaded from variable 'prevPtr')]

In this case, this appears to be a failure of the analysis: the compiler is not recognizing that, for the `while` loop to run zero times, either `delPtr == NULL` (which would have caused an early return), or `delPtr->lineNum == num`, implying `head->lineNum == num` (which would have caused the `else` block to not be run).

That being said, it's not clear to a reader that this code is correct. Restructuring your code to avoid this warning would be advisable.

---

With regard to the question you added in an edit ("Why is there no warning when prevPtr is referenced inside the while loop"): `prevPtr` is only assigned to in the loop. It is not dereferenced, so this is not an error.